# Converting NSString to float

Tags: cocoa, floating-point, nsstring

I am getting a NSString from user inputs that comes to me as something like this: $10,000.00

I have a method that strips the $ off:

```
- (NSString*) stripDollarSign : (NSString*) stringToStrip {

    //check to see if the number is already formatted correctly
    NSRange dollarSignCheck = [stringToStrip rangeOfString:@"$"];
    //only strip it if it has the $
    if (dollarSignCheck.location != NSNotFound) {

        NSString* cleanedString = [stringToStrip substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, stringToStrip.length-1)];
        return cleanedString;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

and my return is 10,000.00 (still a NSString).

If I do this with the cleaned result:

```
float value = [inputString floatValue]
```

I get this:

10.00

If I try converting it to NSDecimal I get 10

```
[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:inputString];
```

What do I have to do to convert this so I get 10,000.00?

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter`: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSNumberFormatter would seem at first like a good way forward:

```
  NSString *currencyAmount = @"$10,000.00";
  NSLocale *englishLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US"];
  NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
  currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
  currencyFormatter.locale = englishLocale;
  NSNumber *number = [currencyFormatter numberFromString: currencyAmount];
  NSLog(@"Got amount: %@", number);
```

Note you may need to set the locale manually on the formatter first - it wasn't handling pound signs well at all when I tested it in my location.

Comment: Thanks, always forget that number formatter is a 2 way street.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setCurrencySymbol:@"$"];
[formatter setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:@","];
[formatter setCurrencyDecimalSeparator:@"."];

NSNumber *n = [formatter numberFromString:@"$10,000.00"];
```

OR

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setPositiveFormat:@"$###,###.##"];
[formatter setLenient:YES]; // This will forgive you for missing out the $ symbol
```

Comment: You'll probably have to set the locale to something American-like, or this solution will have the same problem as the OP.

Comment: Seems to work fine when you are explicit about the symbol, grouping separator and decimal separator.

Comment: True, although there might be an issue with the position of the currency sign - some locales keep it at the end. But the OP stripped it off manually, so that's not really an issue. So I guess you're right!

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. The NSNumberFormatter API doesn't appear to have any reference to currencySymbol position.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `NSString` method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` to remove the comma. E.g.:

```
NSString *stringWithoutComma = [cleanedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```